# Count cells containing all 3 separate words in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I have this excel file containing multiple rows. I wanted to convert the following expression to an excel formula but can't find a reference on how to:

```
COUNTIF(CELL CONTAINS "APPLE" AND CELL CONTAINS "ORANGE" AND CELL CONTAINS "GRAPES")
```

The formula should count all the cells with all those words present in it.

In the example below, the result of the count must be **2** since there are 2 cells which contain all three words.

[image]

How will I do that?

Comment: Do you need to differentiate, for example `Apple` vs `Pineapple`?  If you do, will making the search case sensitive do the trick?  Or do you need something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method is just to use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A11, "*APPLE*", A1:A11, "*ORANGE*", A1:A11, "*GRAPES*")
```

The asterisks are necessary to search for the text anywhere within the cell.

---

Alternatively, and because I already typed it out, you could also use an array formula like so:

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("APPLE", A:A) & SEARCH("ORANGE", A:A) & SEARCH("GRAPES", A:A)), 0, 1))
```

To enter an array formula, hold `CTRL` and `SHIFT` while pressing `ENTER`.

The `SEARCH` function finds text within another text and gives an error when the text is not found.  This function simply concatenates three searches together; if any one of them results in an error, then the concatenation results in an error.  In which case, the ISERROR function will return true.

The `IF` function then returns a `0` when the error happens, and a `1` when an error does not happen.

By using `SUM` with an array formula, the function is applied to every cell in the column `A:A` since that is what was specified, and then sums the results together.